# How to add class in TinyMce table properties

Tags: tinymce

In my application I make my TinyMCE readonly except several word in class `editablecontent`. It work perfectly, by using `contenteditable` attribute from HTML. Now I want to make certain table in TinyMCE editor can edit, only table with class `editablecontent`.

To do that, my plan is when user make an template, to make certain table that editable user set it in Table Properties. When user set it editable than javascript will add class in tag `<table>`. The principle is like add style in table properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TinyMCE 4 and 5, you can use the `table_class_list` to configure a list of classes that can be applied to tables from the dialog you reference.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/table/#table_class_list

Here is a Tiny Fiddle example:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/w8haab

Comment: thank you, than I can replace it on PHP. But now I wondering, any configuration of tinyMCE table to add attribute in table properties? If there is, so I can put attribut of `contenteditable` with value true. in table tag